# Rename a column in AWS Aurora DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I'm like:

```
ALTER TABLE a RENAME COLUMN b TO c
```

And the thing is like:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN b TO c' at line 1
```

I wonder, is it possible to rename a column in Aurora DB? I did my research, but there seems to be like zero docs about these restrictions. How do I rename a column without using `RENAME`? There's a ton of data in that table, so I don't want to create->copy data->delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to rename it after all, using this weird `CHANGE` statement. Let me leave the query here in case anyone faces the same issue in the future:

```
ALTER TABLE a CHANGE b c INT NOT NULL
```

As you can see, it's not perfect, cause one has to specify column type, not just name. So, make sure you replace `INT NOT NULL` with your own type. And in case you don't add `NOT NULL` in there, it might create a nullable column, so beware.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, from perusing the Aurora DB [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Managing.FastDDL.html), I did not see renaming columns as an example operation.  But here is one workaround.  You may add a new column with the name you want, populate it using the data from the old column, and then drop that old column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE a ADD COLUMN (c INT), ALGORITHM = INSTANT;  -- or whatever type you want
UPDATE a SET c = b;                                     -- copy over all data from old to new
ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN b, ALGORITHM = INSTANT;       -- now drop the old column
```

Comment: This is explicitly excluded in the question (and thus the OP was obviously aware of that option): 
"There's a ton of data in that table, so I don't want to create->copy data-> delete."